# Solved - Jenkins not working after upgrading to Java 21

Tags: java, jenkins, upgrade

I recently upgraded my Jenkins to 2.435, after restarting my server and my service, I then attempted to upgrade Java 11 to Java 21 using this post
https://computingforgeeks.com/install-java-jdk-21-openjdk-21-on-ubuntu/

After restarting my server, my Jenkins service does not start anymore. I have tried changing the version allowed in `/etc/init.d/jenkins` :

```
# Work out the JAVA version we are working with:
 JAVA_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\..*".*/\1\2/p;')    << THIS 
        if [ "${JAVA_VERSION}" = "1.8" ]; then
                echo "Correct java version found" >&2
        elif [ "${JAVA_VERSION}" = "21.0.1" ]; then   << THIS 
                echo "Correct java version found" >&2
        else
                echo "Found an incorrect Java version" >&2
                echo "Java version found:" >&2
                "${JAVA}" -version >&2
                echo "Aborting" >&2
                return 2
        fi
```

I still get

```
Dec 07 11:18:23 myApp jenkins[2864]: jenkins: invalid Java version: java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
Dec 07 11:18:23 myApp  jenkins[2864]: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29)
Dec 07 11:18:23 myApp  jenkins[2864]: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29, mixed mode, sharing)
Dec 07 11:18:23 myApp  systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
```

`$ readlink -f $(which java)`

> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21-oracle-x64/bin/java

`$ whereis jenkins`

> jenkins: /usr/bin/jenkins /usr/share/jenkins

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Edit:
this is my `/etc/init.d/jenkins` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /lib/init/init-d-script
# /etc/init.d/jenkins
# debian-compatible jenkins startup script.
# Amelia A Lewis <alewis@ibco.com>
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          jenkins
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Jenkins at boot time
# Description:       Controls Jenkins Automation Server
### END INIT INFO

DAEMON=none
COMMAND_NAME=java
NAME="jenkins"
DESC="Jenkins Automation Server"
PREFIX=/jenkins

check_arguments() {
    # Exit if not supposed to run standalone
    if [ "${RUN_STANDALONE}" = "false" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: Not configured to run standalone" >&2
        return 2
    fi

    # Make sure there exists a java executable, it may not be always the case
    JAVA=$(command -v "${COMMAND_NAME}")
    if [ -z "${JAVA}" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: No Java executable found in current PATH: ${PATH}" >&2
        echo "If you actually have Java installed on the system make sure the executable is in the aforementioned path and that 'command -v ${COMMAND_NAME}' returns the Java executable path" >&2
        return 2
    fi

    # Work out the JAVA version we are working with:
    JAVA_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\..*".*/\1\2/p;')
    if [ "${JAVA_VERSION}" = "1.8" ]; then
        echo "Correct java version found" >&2
    elif [ "${JAVA_VERSION}" = "21.0.1" ]; then
        echo "Correct java version found" >&2
    else
        echo "Found an incorrect Java version" >&2
        echo "Java version found:" >&2
        "${JAVA}" -version >&2
        echo "Aborting" >&2
        return 2
    fi

    # Make sure we run as root, since setting the max open files through
    # ulimit requires root access
    if [ "$(id -u)" -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "The ${NAME} init script can only be run as root" >&2
        return 2
    fi
}

check_tcp_port() {
    service=$1
    assigned=$2
    default=$3
    assigned_address=$4
    default_address=$5

    if [ -n "${assigned}" ]; then
        port=${assigned}
    else
        port=${default}
    fi

    if [ -n "${assigned_address}" ]; then
        address=${assigned_address}
    else
        address=${default_address}
    fi

    count=$(netstat --listen --numeric-ports | grep "${address}:${port}[[:space:]]" | grep -c .)

    if [ "${count}" -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "The selected ${service} port (${port}) on address ${address} seems to be in use by another program "
        echo "Please select another address/port combination to use for ${NAME}"
        return 2
    fi
}

do_start_cmd_override() {
    check_arguments || return "$?"

    # load environments
    if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
        . /etc/default/locale
        export LANG LANGUAGE
    elif [ -r /etc/environment ]; then
        . /etc/environment
        export LANG LANGUAGE
    fi
    export JENKINS_HOME

    # the default location is /var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid but the parent directory needs to be created
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "${PIDFILE}")" || return 2
    chown "${JENKINS_USER}" "$(dirname "${PIDFILE}")" || return 2

    # Verify that the jenkins port is not already in use, winstone does not exit
    # even for BindException
    check_tcp_port "http" "${HTTP_PORT}" "8080" "${HTTP_HOST}" "0.0.0.0" || return 2

    # If the var MAXOPENFILES is enabled in /etc/default/jenkins then set the max open files to the
    # proper value
    if [ -n "${MAXOPENFILES}" ]; then
        [ "${VERBOSE}" != no ] && echo "Setting up max open files limit to ${MAXOPENFILES}"
        ulimit -n "${MAXOPENFILES}" || return 2
    fi
    # notify of explicit umask
    if [ -n "${UMASK}" ]; then
        [ "${VERBOSE}" != no ] && echo "Setting umask to ${UMASK}"
    fi

    # enable access log
    if [ "${JENKINS_ENABLE_ACCESS_LOG}" = "yes" ]; then
        JENKINS_ARGS="${JENKINS_ARGS} --accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file=/var/log/${NAME}/access_log"
    fi

    # start-stop-daemon --chuid/--group doesn't prepare environment variables
    # like HOME, USER, LOGNAME or USERNAME, so re-export these
    SHELL=$(awk -F: "\$1 == \"${JENKINS_USER}\" {print \$NF}" /etc/passwd)
    [ -n "${SHELL}" ] || SHELL=/bin/bash
    HOME="${JENKINS_HOME}" \
        SHELL="${SHELL}" \
        USER="${JENKINS_USER}" \
        PREFIX="${PREFIX}"  \
        LOGNAME="${JENKINS_USER}" \
        USERNAME="${JENKINS_USER}" \
        PWD="${JENKINS_HOME}" \
        eval \
        start-stop-daemon \
        --start \
        --quiet \
        --oknodo \
        --background \
        --no-close \
        --make-pidfile \
        --pidfile "${PIDFILE}" \
        --chdir "${JENKINS_HOME}" \
        --chuid "${JENKINS_USER}" \
        --user "${JENKINS_USER}" \
        --group "${JENKINS_GROUP}" \
        --name "${COMMAND_NAME}" \
        --exec "${JAVA}" \
        ${UMASK:+--umask ${UMASK}} \
        -- ${JAVA_ARGS} -jar "${JENKINS_WAR}" ${JENKINS_ARGS} >>"${JENKINS_LOG}" 2>&1
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "${RETVAL}" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Verify the process did in fact start successfully and didn't just bomb out
    sleep 1
    ATTEMPT=1
    while [ ${ATTEMPT} -le 30 ]; do
        pidofproc -p "${PIDFILE}" "${JAVA}" >/dev/null && break
        [ "${ATTEMPT}" = 30 ] && return 2
        sleep 1
        ATTEMPT=$((ATTEMPT + 1))
    done
    return "${RETVAL}"
}

do_stop_cmd_override() {
    check_arguments || return "$?"
    start-stop-daemon \
        --stop \
        --quiet \
        --oknodo \
        --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
        --pidfile "${PIDFILE}" \
        --chdir "${JENKINS_HOME}" \
        --chuid "${JENKINS_USER}" \
        --user "${JENKINS_USER}" \
        --group "${JENKINS_GROUP}" \
        --name "${COMMAND_NAME}" \
        --exec "${JAVA}" \
        --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "${RETVAL}" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon \
        --stop \
        --quiet \
        --oknodo \
        --prefix=/jenkins \
        --pidfile "${PIDFILE}" \
        --chdir "${JENKINS_HOME}" \
        --chuid "${JENKINS_USER}" \
        --user "${JENKINS_USER}" \
        --group "${JENKINS_GROUP}" \
        --name "${COMMAND_NAME}" \
        --exec "${JAVA}" \
        --retry=0/30/KILL/5
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f "${PIDFILE}"
    return "${RETVAL}"
}

do_status_override() {
    check_arguments || return "$?"
    status_of_proc "${JAVA}" "${NAME}" -p "${PIDFILE}"
}
```

EDIT:

from `/usr/share/java/`
Jenkins seems fully loaded, still cant access it in browser, I get a 404, hardly had issues with nginx before, I'm wondering if I have several jenkins versions installed at different places

```
java -jar ./jenkins.war
Running from: /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
webroot: /root/.jenkins/war
2023-12-07 21:24:34.618+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2023-12-07 21:24:34.789+0000 [id=1] WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2023-12-07 21:24:34.892+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-10.0.18; built: 2023-10-27T01:59:58.245Z; git: 8545fd9bf4cd0d0838f626b405fd4963441546b7; jvm 21.0.1+12-LTS-29
2023-12-07 21:24:35.484+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2023-12-07 21:24:35.557+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: Session workerName=node0
2023-12-07 21:24:36.353+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /root/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
2023-12-07 21:24:36.551+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@51768776{Jenkins v2.435,/,file:///root/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/root/.jenkins/war}
2023-12-07 21:24:36.570+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@32a068d1{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2023-12-07 21:24:36.599+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started Server@35fc6dc4{STARTING}[10.0.18,sto=0] @2830ms
2023-12-07 21:24:36.601+0000 [id=35]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
2023-12-07 21:24:36.924+0000 [id=43]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2023-12-07 21:24:37.280+0000 [id=41]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2023-12-07 21:24:37.740+0000 [id=46]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Mina SSHD API :: Core v2.11.0-86.v836f585d47fa_ (mina-sshd-api-core)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Mina SSHD API :: Core (mina-sshd-api-core 2.11.0-86.v836f585d47fa_)
 - Update required: SSH Credentials Plugin (ssh-credentials 1.19) to be updated to 305.v8f4381501156 or higher
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:552)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-12-07 21:24:37.743+0000 [id=44]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin SSH server v3.312.v1c601b_c83b_0e (sshd)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: SSH server (sshd 3.312.v1c601b_c83b_0e)
 - Failed to load: Mina SSHD API :: Core (mina-sshd-api-core 2.11.0-86.v836f585d47fa_)
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:552)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-12-07 21:24:37.851+0000 [id=47]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Jenkins GIT server Plugin v1.10 (git-server)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Jenkins GIT server Plugin (git-server 1.10)
 - Failed to load: SSH server (sshd 3.312.v1c601b_c83b_0e)
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:552)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-12-07 21:24:37.922+0000 [id=41]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin v3.2.1 (matrix-auth)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin (matrix-auth 3.2.1)
 - Update required: Folders Plugin (cloudbees-folder 6.708.ve61636eb_65a_5) to be updated to 6.815.v0dd5a_cb_40e0e or higher
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:552)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-12-07 21:24:37.924+0000 [id=41]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries v564.ve62a_4eb_b_e039 (workflow-cps-global-lib)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries (workflow-cps-global-lib 564.ve62a_4eb_b_e039)
 - Failed to load: Jenkins GIT server Plugin (git-server 1.10)
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:552)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-12-07 21:24:37.925+0000 [id=41]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries v36.v4c01db_ca_ed16 (pipeline-github-lib)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries (pipeline-github-lib 36.v4c01db_ca_ed16)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries (workflow-cps-global-lib 564.ve62a_4eb_b_e039)
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:552)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-12-07 21:24:37.929+0000 [id=42]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Declarative v2.2064.v5eef7d0982b_e (pipeline-model-definition)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Declarative (pipeline-model-definition 2.2064.v5eef7d0982b_e)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries (workflow-cps-global-lib 564.ve62a_4eb_b_e039)
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:552)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-12-07 21:24:37.951+0000 [id=40]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline v2.6 (workflow-aggregator)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline (workflow-aggregator 2.6)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries (workflow-cps-global-lib 564.ve62a_4eb_b_e039)
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:552)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2023-12-07 21:24:41.333+0000 [id=40]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
2023-12-07 21:24:41.353+0000 [id=40]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins
2023-12-07 21:24:41.369+0000 [id=44]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions
2023-12-07 21:24:42.281+0000 [id=45]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config loaded
2023-12-07 21:24:42.282+0000 [id=45]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config adapted
2023-12-07 21:24:42.297+0000 [id=43]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Loaded all jobs
2023-12-07 21:24:42.310+0000 [id=47]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Configuration for all jobs updated
2023-12-07 21:24:42.604+0000 [id=42]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2023-12-07 21:24:42.628+0000 [id=34]    INFO    hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle#onReady: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Edit #2:
I just tried switching between my Java versions using
`update-alternative`
It seems that using 11 or 17 brings Jenkins back up, 21 causes the issue:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21-oracle-x64/bin/java          352329728 auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1711      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21-oracle-x64/bin/java          352329728 manual mode
```

Comment: What Jenkins version are we talking about? According to https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/platform-information/support-policy-java/ you need to have at least version 2.419

Comment: I upgraded to 2.435
$ grep "version>" /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
 > <version>2.435</version>

Comment: My apologies, it appears you included that in your question to begin with. It looks like you're using systemd to start the service. Have you tried manually starting the command listed in the unit file to see if there's any output that might help you?

Comment: Where can I find this command ? 
I added my init.d/jenkins file to the post

Comment: Oh wow, haven't seen those in a while. From what I can tell from your init file the command to start Jenkins is basically just `java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war`, possibly with some extra parameters (those would be in /etc/default/jenkins probably)

Comment: Added the result

Comment: Aside from outdated plugin warnings it seems Jenkins starts quite nicely when started directly. That causes me to suspect there's an environment problem with regard to the init script rather than a Java 21 problem. Your system might not be able to find the Java executable with the user executing the service, or it might not have permission to access certain folders that the user you just tested with does have permission for

Comment: It looks like using java-17-openjdk brought back Jenkins, I will just stick to that until java-21-openjdk is tested and out

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "until java-21-openjdk is tested and out" since OpenJDK 21 has been out for a few months now. Maybe it's not available in your package manager? You could opt for a release from a different vendor, such as Azul or Eclipse Temurin instead. There's really no harm with sticking with 17 for now though, as it's an LTS that will be supported until september next year (much longer for different vendors). My own Jenkins instance uses the official Docker image, which is still Java 11 (my projects use 21, they're built in Docker containers)